# Flashvars - only supported by SWF?

Tags: adobe, flash, flashvars

I am trying to convert a Flash file that accept variables to a video format. Are there any other formats other then SWF that accept Flashvars as a parameter?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, FlashVars are used only for Flash SWF files, for more details, take a look here : [swfs flashvars](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html)